# Unable to clear two stacked Singularity isolation-span boxes otherwise the flanking boxes get moved

Tags: css, singularitygs

I've built the following test case: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9127157

Problem is, as soon as the layout switches to three columns (starting at the bp 1075px) i have to switch the clearing for the classes .follow and .newsletter to none otherwise the flanking boxes .contact and .thanks get pushed. But now the .newsletter box is stacked above the .follow box.

Is there a way to solve that problem just with CSS (i've tried clearfix mixins but no luck) or is a wrapping div in the html markup necessary for the two classes .newsletter and .follow? I am out of ideas. :(

Thanks in advance Ralf

Comment: That link appears to be broken, can you try re-saving it?

Comment: Strange, sorry… Created a new gist:  https://gist.github.com/rpkoller/9133595

Comment: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9133595  and somehow sassmeister is unable to process the scss into a css,always returning invalid null operation: "null minus 1". optinally i might also upload a sample project on my dropbox and link it.

Comment: Well also uploaded the sample case onto Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8578/clearing.zip

Comment: SassMeister is using Singularity 1.2.x, which has a slightly different syntax, hence the issue compiling. Updated working Sass is available here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9136779

Comment: ahhhhhhh i understand. already figured out the slightly different parts between version 1.1.2 and 1.2. - looks cleaner now. nice! toolkit/kickstart indicates that Toolkit is also as a new alpha version 2.0 on Sassmeister too - looks good as well. Looking forward to the two finals :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way that floats work, this is currently not possible with the HTML you have. Fortunately, the fix is fairly simple: a wrapping `<div>`!

Check out the [updated SassMeister gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9136779) for the full solution.

Basically, what you need to do to accomplish this is wrap `.follow` and `.newsletter` in a wrapping div that has no properties until your breakpoint where you need those two items stacked in the middle. Then, instead of using Singularity to position those items, they're simply 100% width, with `.follow` floating either `left` or `right`, with `.newsletter` clearing the direction that `.follow` floated (or `both)`. Finally, use Singularity to position the containing `<div>`. This will stack them inside of that area and allow `.contact` and `.newsletter` to be positioned normally.

Comment: ahhhhhhh brillian thanks a lot! already guessed the solution with the wrapping div but i was lost half way in my tests before. i did the styling within the div for .follow and .newsletter wrong. now everything is working like a charm. thanks a lot!!! i more and more dig singularities approach. nice!